# Is a dependent type just a vector of types?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, type-theory

You could think of a k-vector of integers as a function of type $\mathbb{Z}/k \to \mathbb{Z}$, associating each member of $\mathbb{Z}/k$ with a single member of $\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, a dependent type $x:A \; \vdash \;B(x):Type$ associates each member $x \in A$ with a single type. (I'm taking this notation from the [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+type) discussion of dependent types.)

If that's a good analogy, then for a family of types $B_n(x)$ dependent on $A$, suppose we define a **vector addition** operation such that

$$(B_1 + B_2)(x) = B_1(x) + B_2(x)$$

and a **scalar multiplication** operation such that

$$(B \cdot T)(x) = B(x) \cdot T$$

It would also seem natural to define an **inner product** as a dependent sum type:

$$B_1 \cdot B_2 = \sum_{x \in A}{B_1(x) \cdot B_2(x)}$$

Would this provide enough structure to define a linear algebra over the semiring of types?

By "semiring of types" I mean the algebraic formulation of datatypes as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190352/abusing-the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-why-does-this-work) and its answers, which show how "scalar" types can be added and multiplied. Since there is no obvious additive inverse, types form only a [semiring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring). However, [this thesis](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/54562608/FULL_TEXT.PDF) suggests that it can make sense to think about a linear algebra over a semiring.

Comment: For a linear algebra you must have a zero object and define addition, additive inverse and multiplication with a scalar. An inner product (dot product) is not necessary. As the zero object we could take the empty type $\emptyset$ (cf. empty set), but how would you define additive inverse, i.e. given a type $A$, how would you define $B$ so that $A + B = \emptyset$?

Comment: The short answer would have to be "no," I think. Dependent types need not have products and coproducts, and they need not behave nicely (e.g. they may not be distributive). Plus it's not clear to me what is supposed to play the role of scalars, what the operations are on the scalars, etc.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine in case it wasn't clear, I added a link to a question that describes the semiring of "scalar" types that I'm imagining as the underlying set.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks — I included an explicit definition of scalar multiplication and a couple of links clarifying why I don't think we need an additive inverse.

Comment: Yes, I'm okay with the semiring structure on closed types (in a type theory that supports such things--not all do). That isn't the problem. The problem is making them *act like scalars*. What type is $B(a)_{a:A}+C(d)_{d:D}$ dependent on? Would your answer to that give you that $B(a)_{a:A}+C(a)_{a:A}=[B(a)+C(a)]_{a:A}$? What would scalar multiplication of $C$ on $B(a)_{a:A}$ be?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I don't think I've understood your questions. Given the stipulation that we are considering only types dependent on A, the first question doesn't apply unless $A = D$. The second question seems to restate the formula for addition that I already gave (since $A = D$ and $x \in A$). And the third question -- well as you can see, I suggested a formula for scalar multiplication after thinking through md2perpe's comment.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine On further reflection, I might not understand what you mean by "act like scalars."

Comment: So you're only interested in dependent types over a fixed base type? Then if types form a semiring, and you can give a semiring a module structure over itself, then sure, you have a module/vector/whatever structure you want to call it. That has nothing to do with dependent types, though, does it? Closed types behave the same. If you're not talking about just talking about a semiring as a vector space over itself, though, I still have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm starting with dependent types that are guaranteed to share the same base type. I want to know whether I can reason about them as if they were vectors.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you've been clear about several aspects of what you mean "treat them as if they were vectors," and I have several times tried to ask you to be clear on A) what the scalars are, B) what the vectors are, C) what vector and scalar addition might be. I asked a very specific question in my last comment: Are you just considering the semi-ring as a module/vector space over itself? In your original post you just show adding and multiplying of families of types, but vector spaces consist of more data than just addition and multiplication.

Comment: I am genuinely trying to ask for more information, but each time I ask about something, you provide information you've already given, so I find myself at an impasse here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81361/discussion-between-malice-vidrine-and-senderle).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I understand! I think we're both coming at this in good faith. I'm afraid I'll have to come back to this tomorrow though.